# is the IP visible when connecting to SSH to a server that is behind "ssh -R"?

Tags: ssh

There is a home router, "Server A".

There is a VPS, "Server B".

I `ssh -R` the SSH port from "Server A" to "Server B" to a non-default port.

**Question**: If someone connects to the "Server B" on the non-default port, will it see the IP of the "Server A"? (does `ssh` reveal it? )

Or can I successfully hide that the non-default SSH port on "Server B" is acutally from "Server A"?

Comment: Are you aware of the SSH-Banner? try e.g. `nc Server-a 22`. it should output something like `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_BLABLA Debian-BLABLA`, with version numbers.

Comment: I think the answer is 'no,' as per [this question on Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61833/can-ssh-port-forwarding-be-detected). I assume that the service running on Server A does not itself risk returning revealing Server A's IP address in-band.